# Unity: Admob Reward Video Ad Doesn't Call Events

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, rewardedvideoad

I'm trying to add an Admob reward video ad to my android game made in Unity. The displays fine but when I close the ad, the reward is never given. I've tested the code in the function and the works fine so I think the problem is that is isn't gettting called. Can anyone help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class textEdit : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Image lifeAdUI;
   static Image lifeAdUIStat;
   public Text adFailUI;
   static Text adFailUIStat;
   public Button lifeButton;

   private static RewardBasedVideoAd videoAd;
   static bool adTime = false;
   static bool adPlaying = false;
   static int pass = 0;
   bool watched;

  // Use this for initialisation
  void Start()
  {
    Button btn = lifeButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(VideoAd);

    videoAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    videoAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
    videoAd.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpening;
    videoAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
    videoAd.OnAdRewarded += HandleOnAdReward;
    videoAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;
    videoAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
    videoAd.OnAdStarted += HandleOnAdStarted;

    lifeAdUIStat = lifeAdUI;
    adFailUIStat = adFailUI;

  }


public static void LoadVideoAd()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitID = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3025391748532285/9122766975";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitID = "";
#else
    string adUnitID = "unexpected_platform";
#endif


    videoAd.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build(), adUnitID);
    pass = pass + 1;

}

void VideoAd()
{
    if (videoAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        videoAd.Show();


    }
    else
    {
        //ad not loaded
    }
}

//Ad Events
public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    if (pass < 2)
    {
        LoadVideoAd();
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(adFailCoro());
    }
}

 public void HandleOnAdOpening(object ssender, EventArgs args)
 {
    adPlaying = true;
 }

 public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    adPlaying = false;
    watched = true;

    if (watched == true)
    {
        control controlScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Control").GetComponent<control>();

        lifeAdUI.enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(controlScript.ExtraLife());
    }
 }

 public void HandleOnAdReward(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    watched = true;
 }

 public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {


 }

  public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {

  }

  public void HandleOnAdStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you called `VideoAd` to show your video Ad but due to some unforeseen reason your video is not loaded yet, or having loading failure, so request to load your Ad Again.

```
void VideoAd()
{
    if (videoAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        videoAd.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        LoadVideoAd();
    }
}
```

Request to load new Video Ad when your Ad is closed by user.

```
public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    adPlaying = false;
    watched = true;

    if (watched == true)  //what is the need of this condition, it always true 
    {
        control controlScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Control").GetComponent<control>();

        lifeAdUI.enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(controlScript.ExtraLife());
        LoadVideoAd();
    }
 }
```

Comment: The watched variable is null to begin with and only is set to true on HandleOnAdRewarded so when the user closes the ad after they've watched it they are rewarded with another life. But the problem is, these HandleOnAd.... functions aren't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Init Admob Unity Plugin

```
using admob;
    Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");//admob id with format ca-app-pub-279xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx
    //Admob.Instance().initAdmob("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716", "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910");
```

Here is the minimal code to create an admob video.

```
Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

Video need to be explicitly shown at an appropriate stopping point in your app, check that the video is ready before showing it:

```
if (Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
  Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
}
```

handle reward

```
Admob.Instance().videoEventHandler += onVideoEvent;
void onVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
{
    Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onRewarded)
    {
        //msg is the reward count.you can handle it now
    }
}
```

ref [admob plugin](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob)